# AWS.DynamoDB: KeyConditionExpression is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I wanted to make a search in DynamoDB equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
from db 
where attr="abc"
```

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
function searchFile(carModel, busMapping, from_date, until_date, location, attackTraffic, isTagged) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config({accessKeyId: '***', secretAccessKey: '***', region: 'us-west-2'});
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    var params = {
        "TableName" : 'db',
        QueryFilter: {
            "attr": {
                ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
                AttributeValueList: [
                    {S: 'abc'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    dynamodb.query(params, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    })
}
```

I got the error message:

> "Expected params.KeyConditionExpression to be a string"

I looked at the AWS documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) and saw that params.KeyConditionExpression must be defined. However, I still didn't understand what is expected to be inside this key. Can you propose something that can make my query work?

Comment: Be sure not to include your access and secret key in your questions.

Comment: And since the keys are still visible in the original question be sure to invalidate them.

Comment: I suggest you stop trying to apply your knowledge of SQL to DynamoDB and take the time to read and understand how DynamoDB works. It is quite different from a relational SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a `query` against DynamoDB you must provide it with the primary/hash/partition key for the table.

> `KeyConditionExpression`: The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key value. The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in the following format: `partitionKeyName` = `:partitionkeyval`

What you probably want is to use the [`scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) method and provide it with a `ScanFilter` instead of a `QueryFilter`:

```
function searchFile(carModel, busMapping, from_date, until_date, location, attackTraffic, isTagged) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config({accessKeyId: '***', secretAccessKey: '***', region: 'us-west-2'});
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    var params = {
        TableName : 'db',
        ScanFilter: {
            attr: {
                ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
                AttributeValueList: [
                    {S: 'abc'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    })
}
```